# Number of tautologies of a given size?

Tags: co.combinatorics, lo.logic, enumerative-combinatorics

Fix some complete set of $L$ logical connectives such as $\{ \wedge, \neg  \}, \{\Rightarrow, \neg \}, \{\ \vee, \wedge, \neg \}, \{ \uparrow\}, \{\wedge, \vee, \neg, \Rightarrow \}$ - I'll assume all formulas involve only the connectives in $L$ (I'm curious how this changes the answers to the questions below).  The *size* of a formula $\phi$ with connectives in $L$ is the number of nodes of $\phi$ where $\phi$ is considered as a labeled tree (with variables labeling the leaves and connectives in $L$ labeling the internal edges).

What is known in terms of bounds on the number of tautologies (using the connectives in $L$) of size $n$ (or maybe size at most $n$ is more natural?)?  Here, I want to consider two tautologies $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ to be the same if there is some bijection on the variables that when applied to the variables in $\tau_1$ yields $\tau_2$.

I'll say a tautology $\tau$ is *reducible* if there is some smaller tautology $\tau_0$ and a substitution $\sigma$ of formulas in for variables into $\tau_0$ yields $\tau$ - otherwise $\tau$ is *irreducible*.

Are almost all tautologies irreducible?  Are there bounds on the number of irreducible (or reducible) tautologies of a given size?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A256120

Comment: Related is the MSE question [Proportion of true statements that are provable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1491438/13130) and some results by [Marek Zaionc](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Marek+Zaionc%22+asymptotic&filter=0).

Comment: i think that universal algebraists miiiight be able to say more about this then logicians. i also think it might be more natural to ask this for a language containing all 16 binary connectives. (There is actually a psychologist Zellweger who created and advocated for such a system.)