# Quantifying Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem and Sparsity of Examples

Tags: nt.number-theory, lo.logic

We know from Gödel's First Incompleteness Theorem that there are true statements in the natural numbers that have no proof. Obviously we know of many that do ("theorems").
Are results known about the relative sparsity of these two sets? For instance, perhaps one could order statements by the number of characters N, and look at true statements. Do we know if "most" true statements are theorems, or the opposite, and does the fraction depend on N? Are Gödel's examples rare jury-rigged freaks, or do they actually become the rule?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421707/number-of-tautologies-of-a-given-size and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1491438/proportion-of-true-statements-that-are-provable

Comment: Also see https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~cristian/aam.pdf

Comment: I left an answer a long time ago arguing that, under any reasonable grammar, a positive density of sentences are of the form "1=1 or S", and are therefore provable  https://mathoverflow.net/a/7902/297 . I wish someone would explain to me how my model differs from Calude and Jurgensen's.

Comment: @SamHopkins Excellent reference.

Comment: Of course, the answer there basically says that the space of true sentences is filled with a lot of junk. Doesn't help with what we'd "really" like to know - "real" theorems vs. distinct true statements w/o proofs. Hmm.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer As Konrad pointed out in your previous answer, I think there's just an error in the Calude-Jurgensen proof - what they actually prove (in the proof of Theorem 5.2 on p.11) is that "the probability that a random string of $n$ logical symbols represents a provable sentence $\to 0$", so they are not conditioning this string being a well-formed grammatical sentence.

Comment: @SamHopkins Btw, this (closed) post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4462934/solution-to-collatz-conjecture illustrates what I was trying to find out, see point (3). Someone pointed out Conway's wondeful http://raganwald.com/assets/fractran/Conway-On-Unsettleable-Arithmetical-Problems.pdf. I _think_ he is driving at the same point, though much more precisely.